# Establishing public key using java

Tags: java, ssh

Is there a way to establish my public key generated using `java.security.KeyPairGenerator` to the **ssh server** that i want to access key based?  That is java equivalent of **ssh-copy-id**?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Portecle` it is an open source software that will enable you to create a `key-store` and generate `Key Pair`. All that is done by GUI no need to write any code or command.

> Portecle is a user friendly GUI application for creating, managing and examining keystores, keys, certificates, certificate requests, certificate revocation lists and more.

you can downloaded from this website: [Portecle](http://portecle.sourceforge.net/)